# Problems creating custom .txt files name in C

Tags: c

I'm having trouble in creating custom file names using *C*.

My goal is to use custom file names in order to print data to them for separate entities.

My current function for the printing to the files is:

```
void output(int t, double rx[], double ry[], double rz[], double vx[], double vy[], double vz[], double fx[], double fy[], double fz[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Npart; i++)
    {
        char name[20];
        sprintf(name, "Part_%d.txt", i);
        fptr = fopen(name, "a");
        fprintf(fptr, "%4d, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e\n", t, rx[i], ry[i], rz[i], vx[i], vy[i], vz[i], fx[i], fy[i], fz[i]);   
    }
}
```

The *fptr* has been initialized using *FILE. 
In this code *Npart* is currently only 2 entities (its set to 2 by a #define), this number will increase after ill rest the function on small number of files, sadly when running this code it seems to work for low numbers of outputs, until it reaches **464** per file to be exact.

After that I get the following error message:

> `timestep made, time is  463 Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

When removing the output functionality and running the code without it no problems occur. Is there any clear mistake I have made in this code?

Comment: Please read up on creating a [mcve]

Comment: Looks like you keep opening new files without ever closing them. That can't be right. You also fail to check the result of `fopen`. If I had to guess, once you hit a certain limit of maximum open files your `fopen` fails, returns nullptr, but you still try to use it in `fprintf`.

Comment: So the problem is not with creating custom names, as in the title, but with writing more than 464 lines to such a file? However, your code does not like it will attempt to write more than one line per file. Could you clarify what you mean by " it seems to work for low numbers of outputs, until 464 per file to be exact". And please make a [mre].

Comment: My apologies, I will try to make a more proper example in future posts. Thank you for the suggestions regarding the closing of the file, that indeed seems to have been the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few obvious problems.

Assuming that you wish to create one file per `Npart`, your code should be something like :

```
void output(int t, double rx[], double ry[], double rz[], double vx[], double vy[], double vz[], double fx[], double fy[], double fz[])
{
  char name[20];
  for(int i = 0; i < Npart; i++)
  {
    sprintf(name, "Part_%d.txt", i);
    fptr = fopen(name, "a");
    if(fptr)
    {
      fprintf(fptr, "%4d, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e\n", t, rx[i], ry[i], rz[i], vx[i], vy[i], vz[i], fx[i], fy[i], fz[i]);
      fclose(fptr);
    }
    else
    {
      // Manage the error
      printf("Could not open %s for appending : %s\n", name, strerror(errno));
    }
  }
}
```

A few questionnable things I've seen with your code :

- Why does `fptr` declared outside of that function?
- Why does `Npart` not a parameter to that function? It would be much more flexible to be able to pass it any number of whatever you're passing in parameters.

---

Update after clarification.

Declare your variable in the smallest possible scope, and put everything together in a structure.

```
typedef struct sWhatever
{
  unsigned int Npart;
  int t;
  double* rx;
  double* ry;
  double* rz;
  double* vx;
  double* vy;
  double* vz;
  double* fx;
  double* fy;
  double* fz;
}
WHATEVER;

void output(WHATEVER * whatever)
{
  FILE* fptr;
  char name[20];
  for(int i = 0; i < whatever->Npart; i++)
  {
    sprintf(name, "Part_%d.txt", i);
    fptr = fopen(name, "a");
    if(fptr)
    {
      fprintf(fptr, "%4d, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e, %10.2e\n", whatever->t, whatever->rx[i], whatever->ry[i], whatever->rz[i], whatever->vx[i], whatever->vy[i], whatever->vz[i], whatever->fx[i], whatever->fy[i], whatever->fz[i]);
      fclose(fptr);
    }
    else
    {
      // Manage the error
      printf("Could not open %s for appending : %s\n", name, strerror(errno));
    }
  }
}

#define Npart (2)
int main(void)
{
  double rx[Npart];
  double ry[Npart];
  double rz[Npart];
  double vx[Npart];
  double vy[Npart];
  double vz[Npart];
  double fx[Npart];
  double fy[Npart];
  double fz[Npart];

  WHATEVER outputStruct;

  outputStruct.Npart = Npart;
  outputStruct.t = 42; // why not?
  outputStruct.rx = rx;
  outputStruct.ry = ry;
  outputStruct.rz = rz;
  outputStruct.vx = vx;
  outputStruct.vy = vy;
  outputStruct.vz = vz;
  outputStruct.fx = fx;
  outputStruct.fy = fy;
  outputStruct.fz = fz;

  output(&outputStruct);
}
```

This way, the content of `WHATEVER` can change and you'll have only minimal changes in your code. You can also pass multiple copies of variables of type `WHATEVER`, which will eventually happen. You can have multiple `WHATEVER` variables with different `Npart` value without you needing to declare multiple copies of `ouput()`. And finally, bonus point, your function becomes reentrant, and produces no side effect on global variables.

(**DISCLAIMER** : *I haven't compiled that code, but it gives you a good idea of what to do.*)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions for the code, glad to say it worked. Somehow the example I used for file writing didn't ever close the file either, but it works now. The error management also seems a valuable addition.
As for your further questions, ```fptr``` is used in multiple sections of the code, thus it is defined outside of this section. ```Npart``` is a paramater that is used in every single function and can, in this case, never be another number in different functions, thus this makes it more easy to change everywhere in one go.

Comment: @I.Hierck If you need to open files in multiple places in code, don't reuse a global variable just because it so happens to be of type `FILE*`. Declare a new variable in the smallest possible scope. You'll run into strange problem very quickly if you continue doing that.  Also, if you find tiedious to pass a variable around, that means your design is bad. The quantity of parameters in your function is also a dead giveaway. Try creating a structure holding all your parameters, including the size of the arrays. I'll add an example to my answer.